# How to rescue an exception from inside a rescue

Tags: ruby, exception, rescue

```
def func 
   some code...
   rescue x,y,z
      do something...
```

I have a function where I'm trying to rescue an exception and then do something inside of rescue. I want to understand how to handle in case there is an exception again inside of the rescue block. This is a corner case and it is definitely necessary.

In case there is an exception again inside of rescue I want to be able to handle it. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply nest a rescue exception inside another rescue exception and you can do so using a number of different approaches depending on the situation but here are a couple:

```
begin

  do_something

rescue

  do_something_else rescue do_this_instead

end
```

OR

```
begin

  do_something

rescue

  begin
    do_something_else
  rescue
    do_this_instead
  end

end
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a ton! Also follow up on the question, if i rescued the Exception and did something, but then again raise the exception the same way system would've thrown the error without the rescue in the first place, How would I do it??

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure that I understand the question.  Could you possibly clarify?

Comment: I meant to ask that if I do something like rescue x,y,z => e , then if i pass this e on to another function as a parameter and raise e there, would it still print the entire error backtrace as it would have originally in the absence of the rescue block.

Comment: I'm sorry, someone else may have to answer that for you.  I personally USE rescue exceptions in my code for various purposes but I have little to no experience dealing with complex error backtracking though.